# override common spring exception handler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am working on a project that implements a common exception handler like this:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CommonExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(final Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a rest template that isn't affected by this exception handling, but no matter what I try all exeptions are handled by the common handler.
Any idea how I can utilize a rest template with a custom error handler that overrides the one above?

Modifications on the common exception handler are not possible, so I have to find a way to work around it.

Comment: Using `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` in your `@RestControllerAdvice` acts as a catch-all for _all_ exceptions thrown. I guess you'll have to either handle more specific exceptions in your advice or not use a `@RestControllerAdvice` at all

Comment: What do you mean by " I want to use a rest template that isn't affected by this exception handling"? The `RestTemplate` is not affected at all by these advices. Do you mean that exceptions caused by the use of the `RestTemplate` end up being handled by this advice?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest two solutions:

- Either you throw specific/new exceptions that are not handled by your `@RestControllerAdvice`, this will may be lead to duplicate exceptions
- Or, catch exception locally at your rest call level:

```java
try {
    return restTemplate.postForObject("http://your.url.here", "YourRequestObjectForPostBodyHere", YourResponse.class);

} catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException httpClientOrServerExc) {

    if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(httpClientOrServerExc.getStatusCode())) {
        // your handling of "NOT FOUND" here  
        // e.g. throw new RuntimeException("Your Error Message here", httpClientOrServerExc);
    } else {
        // your handling of other errors here
    }
```